# Custom HttpMessageConverter for Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm about to dig into the code to find out, but thought I'd ask since I can't find any documentation or references. Spring-data-rest seems to support only JSON (specifically HAL+json). I know I can probably overlay an mvc controller on top of the spring-data-rest endpoint (and autowire the RepositoryRestResource) but that creates a bit of a maintenance issue. I'd like to use content negotiation to allow CSV endpoints if a message converter is available for the domain type.

**Do spring-data-rest endpoints work with custom view implementations?**

*edit (more specific)*: **Do sprint-data-rest endpoints work with custom HttpMessageConverters when serializing responses?**

Comment: Spring Data REST is configured through the [RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java) class.  This class has a method named `defaultMessageConverters` that adds Jackson message converters to the configuration.  You may try extending the class and overriding the method to add your own converters to see if that works.

Comment: Tried overriding this (actually used `configureHttpMessageConverters`) and ensured it was called, but it doesn't seem to work. I made sure that my HttpMessageConverter was called in regular spring-mvc Controllers, then set a breakpoint in the `canWrite` method of the converter. It doesn't seem to get called when using the spring-data-rest endpoints. I'm not sure about this, but based on my reading of `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`, the converters might only be used when deserializing request content or method arguments, not for serialization. Seems very promising though.

Comment: I have tried adding custom converters to the Spring Data REST configuration and it does work. See [my sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/blob/master/36851449/src/main/java/org/example/Application.java). You will see that I have added a JAXB converter to the configuration. The converter does get invoked but fails to serialize objects because it expects the classes to be annotated with `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlType` and Spring Data REST passes instances of type `PersistentEntityResource` to it. A custom converter should be able to overcome this hurdle.